# jQuery Plugin to show stacked panels or div's?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery plugin which shows div's in a stacked formation like the formation below. Each div is shifted by a few pixels horizontally and vertically than the one above it. When I click on any div's edge, it gets focus and it becomes the one on top. (they change their z-index). Very similar to how a user switches between the windows in Windows in the image below.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: All those questions with unaccepted answers where from '08 & '09 when you had to wait for few days before SO accepted an answer. I didn't go back after the period elapsed. Anyways I went through them now I accepted a whole bunch. If you had an answer I hope the low rate didn't stop you from posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default) - Dialog box does work for you.

Here is the code:

```
function stackDialogs(dialogs, x, y){
    for (var i = 0; i < dialogs.length; i++){
        x += 20;
        y += 20;
        dialogs[i].dialog("option", "position", [x,y]);
    }
}
```

Checkout example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5y8uq/).

Comment: Do you mean creating several dialogs and manually positioning them?

Comment: Yes. By default they are positioned on top of each other. I doubt there is any special plugin to change window coordinates.